# Convert System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit to int in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, type-conversion

How can I convert from an ASP.NET [Unit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctewx7ch(v=VS.100).aspx) structure to int in c#? Or reverse?

Comment: What unit? do you mean the ASP.NET Unit class?

Comment: (it's a structure) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.unit.aspx

Comment: asp.net unit like webcontrol.height

Answer (score 12):

The Unit type has a [Value property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.unit.value%28v=VS.71%29.aspx). This is a double, but you can cast it to an int if you want. The casting may cause a loss of precision, but you are probably aware of that.

To create a Unit just use the [constructor that takes an int](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa334646%28v=VS.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

If you mean the **[Unit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.unit.aspx)** class:

> The Unit class can represent values
>   only between -32768 and 32767.

But it depends if you want the Pixel or Percentage value.

- `myUnit.Value` will get the value as pointed out.
- Use the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4b1sf2c9(v=VS.100).aspx) `public Unit(int value)` to convert back.

---

<strike>If you mean a **[uint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0sksh43(VS.71).aspx)**: there's 2 possible obvious ways:</strike>

```
int n = Convert.ToInt32(myUint);
int n = (int)myUint;
```

Answer (score 2):

For ASP.NET Unit:

```
unit.IsEmpty ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(unit.Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Unit.Value property. It will return double and you can cast it to int

Something like `(int)xyz.Value`

WEhere xyz is the unit variable

To convert int to unit use `new Unit(value)`

Answer (score 0):

Probably he need this:

```
 int myInt = 1;
 uint myUint = (uint)myInt;

 uint myUint = 1;
 int myInt = (int)myUint;
```

Comment: Your code will not work properly in many cases ... You need to use the Convert Object to convert from int to Uint and reverse

Answer (score 0):

The `Value` property returns a dobule, that you can convert to an integer:

```
int h = (int)someControl.Height.Value;
```

However, the conversion might not make sense for some unit types. If you don't know for certain that the unit is of a specific type, you would want to check the `Type` property first.

Answer (score -1):

```
Convert.Toint32( UInt );
```

I guess u meant UInt not Unit

EDIT : Ok thought you meant uint sorry

Comment: Just keep in mind that there is a big difference between UInt and Int32. When converting them you might end up with a wrong result (if the UInt exceeds 2147483647).

Comment: Thats always the risk when converting different numbers

Comment: Not when converting Int32 to Int64 or short to long etc. ;)